# nHibernate HasMany Limit

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table (say object A) and it CAN be referenced by multiple objects of type B. This warrents a HasMany relationship from object A to object B (and a References relationship from B to A) BUT I know some of these object A's just have the one child object B - is there any way I can limit the HasMany mapping to a single object, instead of an IList?

Rather than have an object B AND an IList<> of object B within my object A entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a [one-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) mapping, but this won't work in your case since you said that only a subset of these entities have a single child object.
Another idea would be to create a property which will return the first object in the hasmany set, but you cannot use this in queries (LINQ, HQL or criteria)

```
     public B Related {
        get {
            return ListOfB.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done, but I was hoping there was another way. If not, I can live with the interim solution.